# how to apply codeigniter file uploader in our project?

Tags: codeigniter

I make simple file uploader with codeigniter and then as my espect the program running well , when I try to apply in my project. method do_upload is executed but file can't uploaded. this is my code

**Controller path**  `C:\xampp\htdocs\pasar\application\modules\crud`

**Upload path** `C:\xampp\htdocs\pasar\uploads`

view  v_foto.php

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/crud/c_foto/do_upload' ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<h3>Upload Foto </h3>
<input type="file">
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

controller c_upload.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_foto extends MY_Controller {

function __construct() {

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

}

public function index() {

}

function do_upload(){

//preferences

$config['upload_path'] ='.uploads/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

$config['max_size'] = '100';

$config['max_width']  = '1024';

$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){

    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    echo "Upload failed";

} else {

    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    
    echo "Upload sukses";

}

}

}
```

After button upload clicked then the browser display upload failed, please give me corection, thanx

Comment: You need to use PHP function [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** thing noticed your missing is `name="userfile"` in input.

**Second:** on your controller you do not have a view in index()

**Third:** create a variable called `$input_name = "userfile";` Just above the do upload. And then in the **do_upload** add `$input_name` like `$this->upload->do_upload($input_name)`

**Fourth:** thing noticed

`$config['upload_path'] ='.uploads/';`

Change to

`$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';`

Codeigniter Docs http://www.codeigniter.com/docs/

Userguide: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html

This is single file upload only.

View

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('index.php/crud/c_foto/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php

// MX HMVC 
// CI Codeigniter
class C_foto extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {

        /*
             Main Directory: 

             application
             uploads
             system
             index.php

        */

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '0'; // No Limit
        $config['max_width']  = '0'; // No Limit
        $config['max_height']  = '0'; // No Limit

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        // Set your input name from <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

        $input_name = "userfile";

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($input_name))
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've worked wolfgang1983, now appears a new message   The upload path does not appear to be valid, after that

Comment: path does not appear to be valid' , after that I change   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; to  $config['upload_path'] =  base_url().'uploads/', I think there is little progress but have not been successful

Comment: Is your uploads folder in main directory of project?

Comment: in this place "C:\xampp\htdocs\pasar\uploads",  so I call  base_url(). to make dynamic location .

Comment: actualy I get new progress  after change this code : $this->load->library('upload', $config); to $this->upload->initialize($config);  and then message error become this, "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file"

Comment: Well just change the size of upload default set at 100 could use 5000  or 0 for no limit Read manual you can also change with and height